# nginx regex location not matching number followed by specific letter

Tags: nginx

I tested my regex on a site and it matched, but I can't get it to work in nginx. What am I missing?

I want to find any parameter with string `window` that has numbers and a d (not h for hour) like:

```
?window=30d&some-other-arg
```

and not match:

```
?window=24h&some-other-arg
```

pattern that works on https://regex101.com/r/5f6WpI/1

```
~ window=([^&]*)+d
```

And nginx location is:

```
location ~ window=([^&]*)+d {
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the regex. But the part of the URL that you are testing is called the query string, which cannot be tested using a `location` or `rewrite` directive. What are you trying to do inside the `{}`s? You may be able to use `if ($arg_window ~ ^(.*)d$) { ... }` instead.

Comment: Thanks!
I have a new question based on this but your answer is correct for what I asked.